# Is the metric for the sequence space $s$ always convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $s$ be the space of all the sequences, bounded or unbounded, of complex numbers. The book defines the metric of the space as
$$
  d(x,y)=\displaystyle{\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{j}}\frac{|\xi_{j}-\eta_{j}|}{1+|\xi_{j}-\eta_{j}|}}
$$
Where $x=(\xi_{1},\xi_{2},\cdots)$ and $y=(\eta_{1},\eta_{2},\cdots)$. One property from metric spaces requires the metric to be finite. I'm checking for that series to be finite, my attempt was to compare with the following series
$$
  \displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{1+k}}
$$
Nonetheless, it diverges. Also, I know that the series
$$
 \displaystyle{\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{j}}}
$$
converges since it is geometric.
How do I show that series is finite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{2^{j}}\frac{|\xi_{j}-\eta_{j}|}{1+|\xi_{j}-\eta_{j}|}\le\frac1{2^j}$$
so the series converges by the comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

$0 \leq \frac {|\xi_j-\eta_j|} {1+|\xi_j-\eta_j|} \leq 1$. Multiply by $\frac  1 {2^{j}}$ and use the fact that  $\sum \frac  1 {2^{j}} <\infty$.